# How do I remove a zip file in Dotnetzip

Tags: c#, memorystream, dotnetzip

I am trying to delete a `zip` file in `DotNetZip` as it is like `transaction`(either do it full or not at all).

Currently, I have `incremented` my `count` twice, on purpose to break the app and see if it saves the `zip`.

Well it does, it saves the `zip` with 2 files instead of 3 and as I said I want it to behave like a `transaction`.

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputdirectory))
        {
            var count = 0;

        //    string invoiceNumber = documents[count].GetElementsByTagName("InvoiceNumber")[count].InnerText + ".xml";

            if (documents.Count == 1)
            {
                string invoiceNumber = documents[0].GetElementsByTagName("InvoiceNumber")[0].InnerText + ".xml";
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
                SaveFiles(documents[0], invoiceNumber, settings);
                resultValue = InvoiceResult.Success;
            }
            else
            { 
                foreach (var document in documents)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string invoiceNumber = documents[count].GetElementsByTagName("InvoiceNumber")[0].InnerText + ".xml";

                    count++;

                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            document.Save(memoryStream);

                            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            zip.AddEntry($"{invoiceNumber}.xml", memoryStream);

                                zip.Save();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        var wrongZip = ZipFile.Read(outputdirectory);                        
                        wrongZip.Dispose();
                        resultValue = InvoiceResult.CannotCreateZipFile;
                   //     throw new IOException($"Zip file in path {outputdirectory} has already been created. Please delete file if you want to make a new one.");
                    }
                    count++;

                }
            }
        }
```

I have found this article on `Stackoverflow`.

[DotNetZip how to delete a file after extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931692/dotnetzip-how-to-delete-a-file-after-extracting)

It said read the `stream` of the `zip` and then `Dispose` of it. I have tried that but the `zip` file still exists.

No errors, just does not delete the file.

Comment: is it okay to just use  System.IO.File.Delete(outputdirectory);  
I mean do I have to read and dispose of the file as well?

Comment: Just use the `System.IO.File.Delete` library to delete the zip AFTER disposing of it in the `DotNetZip`library (not tested)

Comment: That's not what that says... it just says the zipfile object needs to be disposed. Just put your try-catch block _around_ the `using` block. You said it needs to fully abort on fail anyway, and then the object is already disposed and you can always safely delete it.

Comment: By the way... is there any point to saving the zip file in between adding files? Isn't it much simpler to just save once at the end? Then you shouldn't have incomplete zipfiles at all. Or is that because you're using `MemoryStream`s as source for the files? Because that smells a lot like a [Schlemiel The Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm), since it'll rewrite the whole zipfile each time.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot of chaos in that code; the combination of a counter and a `foreach`, looped re-saving of the zipfile, unnecessary re-reading of an already-open zipfile...

Since you literally said that any error in the saving process should lead to a full abort, it makes a lot more sense to put the `try-catch` *around* the `ZipFile`'s `using` block. One of the functions of a `using` block is to clean up the object even in case of an exception, after all.

As for the looped re-saving, personally, I'd simply make an array of `MemoryStream` objects, and in each loop iteration, fill one in, link it into the `ZipFile` as file, and save the `ZipFile` only once, *after* the whole loop. You can then safely dispose the `MemoryStream` objects from the array. This way, they all exist simultaneously at the moment you save the `ZipFile`. And if you only dispose them after the `ZipFile`'s `using` block you are 100% sure the `ZipFile` object no longer needs them.

If you do it this way, nothing will ever be written in case an error occurs, since it never gets to the `zip.Save()` line. So there will be no need to delete anything, either.

```
try
{
    Int32 docCount = documents.Count;
    MemoryStream[] streams = null;
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputdirectory))
    {
        if (docCount == 1)
        {
            string invoiceNumber = documents[0].GetElementsByTagName("InvoiceNumber")[0].InnerText + ".xml";
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
            SaveFiles(documents[0], invoiceNumber, settings);
            resultValue = InvoiceResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            streams = new MemoryStream[docCount]
            // Since we need an index for both the documents and streams array,
            // use 'for' and not 'foreach'
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < docCount; ++i)
            {
                var doc = documents[i];
                string invoiceNumber = doc.GetElementsByTagName("InvoiceNumber")[0].InnerText + ".xml";
                MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
                // Store stream in array so you can dispose it later
                streams[i] = str;
                doc.Save(str);
                str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                zip.AddEntry($"{invoiceNumber}.xml", str);
            }
            zip.Save();
        }
    }
    if (streams != null)
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < docCount; ++i)
            if (streams[i] != null)
                streams[i].Dispose();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    resultValue = InvoiceResult.CannotCreateZipFile;
}
```

There do seem to be some details missing from this, though. The 1-file logic doesn't seem to use the `ZipFile` at all, meaning the `ZipFile`'s `using` block can technically just be placed inside the `else`. Also, the multiple-file logic never sets the `resultValue`.